# How to calculate the commutation relation for generator of $SO(3)$ with finite rotation in the group?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, representation-theory, rotation, lie-algebra

I am trying to show that $$e^{-iX_3\theta}X_+e^{iX_3\theta} = e^{-i\theta}X_+$$ where $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are the generators of $SO(3)$, which obey the usual commutation relations of their Lie algebra, and $X_+ := \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}(X_1+iX_2)$ is the raising operator.

I assume that the method involves calculating the commutator $[X_+,e^{iX_3\theta}]$, but I'm having a lot of trouble evaluating this. It feels vaguely familiar to something I learnt a few years ago, but if someone could show explicitly what I'm forgetting that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try differentiating both sides of the equation wrt theta

Comment: Doesn't this require assuming that I already know the answer, which isn't really showing it

Comment: If you don't know the rhs a priori then you will produce a homogeneous first order differential equation which you can solve up to a constant (fixed by looking at theta = 0 say)

Answer (score 3):

You simply apply the standard [Hadamard lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_identity),
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_{e^X}Y = e^{X}Y e^{-X} = e^{\operatorname{ad} _X} Y \\ =Y+\left[X,Y\right]+\frac{1}{2!}[X,[X,Y]]+\frac{1}{3!}[X,[X,[X,Y]]]+\cdots,
$$
where $[X_3,X_+]=X_+$, so that the l.h.side reduces to
$$
X_+  -i\theta X_+ +\frac{(-i\theta)^2}{2!} X_+ +... = e^{-i\theta} X_+.
$$

Geometrically, it is straightforward to identify this rotation around $\hat z$ as, anti-clockwise,
$$
X_1 ~~\mapsto \cos\theta ~X_1 +\sin\theta ~X_2,\\
X_2 ~~\mapsto \cos\theta ~X_2 -\sin\theta ~X_1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: call the left-hand side $f(\theta)$ so $f(0)=X_+$. @lux notes we need only prove $f^\prime=-if$. By the product rule, this is equivalent to $[X_+,\,X_3]=-X_+$.

Comment: Apologies if I am being quite slow here: So we have $f' = i[f,X_3]$, but how does this then become $f'+if=0$, or what is it's equivalence to the product rule?

Comment: @MC2k The derivative is $e^{-iX_3\theta}(-iX_3)X_+e^{iX_3\theta}+e^{-iX_3\theta}X_+(iX_3)e^{iX_3\theta}=ie^{-iX_3\theta}[X_+,\,X_3]e^{iX_3\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the commutator relation between $X_3$ and $X_+$:
$$[X_3,X_+]=X_+$$

Spell out the commutator, multiply by $(-i\theta)$, add $X_+$,
and factorize a little bit. You get
$$(1-i\theta X_3)X_+(1+i\theta X_3)+O(\theta^2)=(1-i\theta)X_+$$

Here we used the [big-$O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) because for small $\theta$
the exact form of the $\theta^2$ term is not really important.

We get an equation, which is not restricted to small $\theta$,
by replacing $\theta$ by $\theta/n$
and iterating the equation $n$ times.
$$\left(1-i\frac{\theta}{n}X_3\right)^nX_+\left(1+i\frac{\theta}{n}X_3\right)^n
+O\left(\frac{\theta^2}{n^2}n\right)
=\left(1-i\frac{\theta}{n}\right)^nX_+$$

Now we can go to the limit $n\to\infty$.
The big-$O$ term becomes zero.
And for the other terms we can use the [definition of the
exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$.
We finally get:
$$e^{-i\theta X_3}X_+e^{+i\theta X_3}=e^{-i\theta}X_+$$